# Wrapping nested ranges in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am trying to visualize some source code data in JavaScript:

Example Input:

```
public String newVar = "so new";
```

Then this input will be matched and the output will be the starting position and the length of all matches, as well as some other data.

So for example it will match "public" in the example input code above:

```
type: "INSERT"
dstLength: 6
dstPos: 0
...
```

I want to wrap all the matches in a span tag. This is easy for a single match, just add a opening and closing `span` tag at index 0 and 6 of the string.

```
<span class="ins">public</span> String newVar = "so new";
```

The problem now is, if we look at the data for the next match "String", it will be off because the string just got a lot longer...

"String" data would be:

```
type: "INSERT"
dstLength: 6
dstPos: 7
...
```

With the same approach we will just wrap `lass="`with a span tag and this is not what i want.

Is there any good way of replacing all those items together in one step without having to recalculate anything?
The matches are not sorted by occurrence in any way and can be nested, so for the input example that means there could be a match for the whole line `public String newVar = "so new";`as well.

Comment: You are encountering the double-encoding problem - ie your starting to "encode" and then looking at the encoded string instead of the original.  I'd suggest a rethink, by parsing the source string into a new string rather than iteratively updating the same string (ie don't replace source by new each time).

Comment: i still didn't understood your question :(

Comment: I get what you are saying, that would fix the issue with highlighting the wrong part of the source code, but then I end up creating tons of strings with no real clue how to put them back together to form a final highlighted string that i can display.

Comment: My bad - you're already running the the matches first (it wasn't clear) - so you have a number of objects, you're not applying one and then reparsing.  I'll remove my comment shortly.

Comment: If you can remove the requirement that they can be nested, then just sort by dstPos and run in reverse order.